# wxPython-demo-4.0.0b2/Lynux - miscellaneous/Sound demo asserts "Attempt to play invalid wave data"

Tags: python, wxpython

I am sure something simple is happening, like I need to install some RPM package or other but here is my question:

running wxPython-demo-4.0.0b2

using either Wing Personal 6.0.7-1 or WingIDE

Platform/OS: Fedora Linux 26 Workstation (installed yesterday)

I have SDL installed

In the demo, in the wyPython Demos panel on the left, open "miscellaneous/Sound" click the 'PlaySound 1 (sync)' (or any) button and I get:

```
File "/media/psf/Dropbox/python/wxPython-demo-4.0.0b2/demo/Sound.py", line 28, in OnButton1
  sound.Play(wx.adv.SOUND_SYNC)

wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "IsOk()" failed at /home/vagrant/wxPython-4.0.0b2/ext/wxWidgets/src/unix/sound.cpp(581) in DoPlay(): Attempt to play invalid wave data
```

I have tried to use `wx.adv.sound` in my python project and it fails to play ANY sound format, regardless of how the file is formatted.

So I figure that because it won't play even in the demo using a sound file shipped WITH the demo, there is a dependency that I don't have installed. Or it's an open issue

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I got it working. forgot to mention I'm running Linux in a VM. Demo was installed on a shared volume prepared by the host system and mounted in Linux.

When I copied the demo to the home folder in Linux, the sound playing works.

This assert could be improved.